# Unknown property 'VisualforceArrayList.EHS_Task__c'

Tags: triggers, controller, salesforce, apex, visualforce

I am getting error "Unknown property 'VisualforceArrayList.EHS_Task__c'" while deploying VF page. Below is the page code:

```
<div style="border-bottom: 1px solid gray;border-right: 1px solid gray;padding: 2px 10px;">
                    <strong class="" >Task:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="task" id="task" class="frminput" value = "{!getEHS.EHS_Task__c}"></input>
                </div>
```

Controller:

```
public  class ES_EHSReportGeneration {


    public Apexpages.Standardcontroller cntrl ;     
    public PageReference page; 
    public String id ='' ;
    public List<EHS_Pre_Job_Brief__c> getEHS{get;set;}
 
public ES_EHSReportGeneration(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
            this.cntrl = controller ; 
            this.page = ApexPages.currentPage();
            this.id = page.getParameters().get('id');
               
}   

 public ES_EHSReportGeneration(){

    getEHS = [Select id, EHS_Task__c from EHS_Pre_Job_Brief__c where id= :id limit 1] ; 


}
```

Please check and advise what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`getEHS{get;set;}` - this counts as double "get".

And the fact you have 2 constructors means you'll have errors (1 constructor figures out the record id, 2nd constructor runs the query. They won't run together so it won't do what you want).

And you declared a `List<EHS_Pre_Job_Brief__c>` variable but in VF you plan to access it as a single record (`{!getEHS.EHS_Task__c}`, not `{!getEHS[0].EHS_Task__c}` or something).

Many ways to fix this, read up about controller extensions, getters. You've confused yourself a lot here, copy-paste programming or something. Don't rush so much, find some trailheads for basics.

```xml
<apex:page standardController="EHS_Pre_Job_Brief__c" extensions="ES_EHSReportGeneration">
    <strong class="" >Task:</strong>
    <input type="text" name="task" id="task" class="frminput" value = "{!jobBrief.EHS_Task__c}"></input>
</apex:page>
```

and

```apex
public  class ES_EHSReportGeneration { 
    public jobBrief {get;set;}
 
    public ES_EHSReportGeneration(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        jobBrief = (EHS_Pre_Job_Brief__c) controller.getRecord();
        Id i = controller.getId();
        if(i != null){
            jobBrief = [SELECT Id, EHS_Task__c FROM EHS_Pre_Job_Brief__c WHERE Id= :i];
        }
}
```